# Using JSQMessagesViewController without pod

Tags: swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to use `JSQMessagesViewController` in my swift project without using pod.

I downloaded the library from github and trying to run the Swift Example

- in Swift Example project, I have added the JSQMessagesViewController folder.
- I have a briding header with `#import "JSQMessages.h"` in it.
- I have -ObjC other linker flag
- My library search paths is empty

I am getting follwoing errors:

> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-F/Users/Kashif/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftExample-ervbzkaxwylnjiabtkvejlktxmtv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JSQMessagesViewController'
>
> ld: framework not found JSQMessagesViewController
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

What do you think I am missing?

Alternatively, if someone knows another library to achieve chat bubbles? as JSQMessagesViewController is now deprecated anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Ya you want to check out [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit) It is the next version of the project but more focused on being all swift. Its still relatively new but version 0.11.0 just shipped and it has most of the features that `JSQMessagesViewController` had. Let me know if you need more help they have an active slack group you can join

Answer (score 0):

Ya you want to check out [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit) It is the next version of the project but more focused on being all swift. Its still relatively new but version 0.11.0 just shipped and it has most of the features that `JSQMessagesViewController` had. Let me know if you need more help they have an active slack group you can join or just post more questions here on StackOverflow.

As for your question about not using pods It is possible to add any framework to a project but you miss out on what the "Dependency Manager" provides which is dependency management. IE any time a new feature is added to a framework the only way for you to get it in your project is to download the latest and add it manually to your project.

You also need to make sure you are adding the right thing. Essentially there is a .xproject but that may not be what you want to add to your project because that may be the "Project" that creates the `Framework` that actually gives you the capabilities you are looking for. So you may need to download the project open it in `Xcode` Build it and then find the "Product" which would be the framework the project produces and add that to your project.

`CocoaPods` or `Carthage` help you do that and update when new versions are available.

Comment: It looks very promising. Is it possible to install it manually without pod?

Comment: Ya you can add pretty much any framework to a project manually. But may I ask why. The reason for `CocoaPods` or `Carthage` are to make it easy for you to update your dependencies. Without them the only way to get new features added to a framework into your project is to re-download the entire `framework` and add it to your project.

Comment: You also need to make sure you are adding the right thing. Essenturally there is a .xproject but that may not be what you want to add to your project because that may be the "Project" that creates the `Framework` that actually gives you the capabilities you are looking for. So you may need to get project open it in `Xcode` Build it and then find the "Product" which would be the framework the project produces and add that to your project.